# Is it possible to export organic groups global roles using features?

Tags: organic-groups, features

I like to keep functionality that I build in features, both for version control and deployment.

I'm new to using Organic Groups and I wanted to know if it's possible to add an organic gorups global role to a feature.  I couldn't see any mention of this when I tried to recreate my feature through the UI or drush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue for this in the organic groups queue.  [features integration for organic groups permissions and roles](http://drupal.org/node/1349754).  You may also want to install strongarm and see if that helps you store the configuration settings that are stored as variables.